# onBackPressed() is not working

Tags: android, button, layout, onbackpressed

In One `Activity` class I am using different layouts.

By disabling one layout I am moving to another layout. But I am facing an issue while pressing the back button. It is coming to the first layout while I am in third layout.

Here is my Code:

I have used 3 buttons to move to another layout.

```
public void continueToDelivery(View view) {
    relativeLayoutLogin.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    relativeLayoutDelivery.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
    relativeLayoutPayment.setVisibility(view.GONE);  
}   

public void continueToPayment(View view) {
    relativeLayoutDelivery.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    relativeLayoutPayment.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
}

public void placeOrder(View view) {
    relativeLayoutPayment.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    relativeLayoutSuccess.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `onBackPressed` in your activity then:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      if(isThirdLayoutVisible)
       //go to second layout
      else if(isSecondLayoutVisible)
      //go to first layout
     else 
     //exit from app
    }
```